# Pyspark NaiveBayes model predicted output to Csv file

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pyspark

I am using separate train and test csv file of 345Mb and 21GB size having 13 rows and max. 80 million rows.

NaiveBayes Model codes-

```
# Reading files
data="C:/csv/train2004.txt"
test="C:/csv/ascii20041.asc"
#Data into RDD
train=sc.textFile(data).map(lambda x: x.split(","))
test=sc.textFile(test).map(lambda y: y.split("    "))

#extract header
header = train.first()  
header1 = test.first()
print(header)
print(header1)

#Removing Header Row
train = train.filter(lambda Row: Row!=header)
#test=test.filter(lambda Row: Row!=header)
print(train.first())
print(test.first())
train = train.map(lambda x: x[4:17])
test = test.map(lambda x: x[3:16])
print(train.first())
print(test.first())

# Reading required column
train = train.map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(x[0],x[1:13]))
test = test.map(lambda y: LabeledPoint(y[0],y[1:13]))
print(train.first())
print(test.first())

#Naive Bayes Model training
model = NaiveBayes.train(train, 1.0)

#Prediction and save as Test file
predictionAndLabel = test.map(lambda p: (model.predict(p.features), p.label))
print(predictionAndLabel.first())
predictionAndLabel.saveAsTextFile('c:/csv/mycsv.csv')

#Accuracy Checking
accuracy = 1.0 * predictionAndLabel.filter(lambda (x, v): x == v).count() /  test.count()
print('model accuracy {}'.format(accuracy))
```

ERROR:

> An error occurred while calling o5072.saveAsTextFile. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 365.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.0 in stage 365.0 (TID 460, localhost)

Still I am facing issue in:

1. Saving 'predictAndLabel'.'saveAsTest' predicted output to an text file.
2. To Join predictAndLabel result with test input  with its reference of row number.

Answer (score 0):

In these two lines:

```
train = train.map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(x[0], x[1:13]))
test = test.map(lambda y: LabeledPoint(y[0], y[1:13]))
```

you pass list of strings to `LabeledPoint` which re not a valid input. It should be

- NumPy `array`
- list
- `pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector`
- `scipy.sparse column matrix`

of **numeric types**.

Comment: Hi James Z, can you provide any example code so i will manipulate same to get  results.